# WordPress image grid with on-hover div display

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hover

I am wondering what would be the easiest way to make a 3x3 grid of pictures and have a mouse over display a div with a lengthy description for each image? 
I am planning to make this on a wordpress page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for the easiest way, you can do it without javascript, but it will have somewhat limited support (at least for older browsers .. *cough* IE *cough*).
The HTML will be something like:

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li>
        <img src="some_image_here" alt="some_description" />
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The description itself can be an absolute element which is hidden below the thumb (which has `overflow: hidden;`) and is made visible on thumb hover.
An example of my idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/SjF3N/

Of course you can tweak the size of the thumbs to match your needs, I'm just trying to fit it in the jsfiddle layout.